# Difference between dbo and [dbo]

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a difference between writing the following in a query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Product
```

compared to:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Product]
```

Is one better than the other or does it not matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No difference.  The purpose of the brackets is to deal with cases where you have db objects that have names that might confuse the DBMS, e.g. objects with spaces in their names or which are named after reserved words like `Trigger` (among other reasons, as pointed out in the comments).

For the purposes of consistency, you can surround all your "objects" (schemae like `dbo`, tables, and columns, etc.) with brackets.

```
SELECT [MyColumn] FROM [MyDatabaseName].[dbo].[My Table Name]
```

Note, I think that naming your objects with "unconventional" names, is generally bad practice (with some exceptions).  But obviously if you're just writing queries against existing schemae that you don't control, it is what it is.

Comment: Ah, cool. Thank you for the information. I never include spaces in object names so it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Or if your DB object is named after a reserved word like `trigger`, but this is bad practice as well.

Comment: I would also like to add, the brackets is also used to handle objects with hyphens in them like [object-name]

Comment: Or also if your object has a double quote `"` in its name, which is probably an even worse practice. If your object has a space, you can enclose it with double quotes as well.

Comment: @rory.ap the bracket for `[dbo]` is for decorating purposes as it is always one word right?